# Unbalanced Parenthesis in a for loop in batch

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, batch, batch-file

`@echo off 
FOR /l %%A in (0,1,30) do (
 set /a results=1600 + !RANDOM! %% (1900 - 1600 + 1)
echo %%A--!results! 

)`

When I run this I keep getting error "Unbalanced parenthesis" in windows xp and
when I run this in win 7 I get error "Missing operator".

Need Help for newbie.

Thanks

Comment: This question might be more relevant on Stack Overflow, since it's a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I escaped the ( ) that were within the for loop, then no error.

but to notice there was a problem I did `echo set /a ......` and the output had lines like `set /a results=1600 + 14199  (1900 - 1600 + 1` so I could see it looked like maybe the `)` was getting eaten up and taken to be a closing parenthesis of the for loop. So I thought to escape them.

also the setlocal line was required(at least with enabledelayedexpansion).. so that !RANDOM! would come out right, otherwise you also get an error.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off 
FOR /l %%A in (0,1,30) do (
 set /a results=1600 + !RANDOM! %% ^(1900 - 1600 + 1^)
echo %%A--!results! 
)
endlocal
```

^^ tested in windows 7.